# How to scan the Firebase Database even before the user has registered?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I want to scan the database while registering a user to check if a certain 'username' is available or taken. I tried it using this code:

```
mDatabase.child("usernames").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                    if (dataSnapshot.getValue() != null) {
                                        if (dataSnapshot.getValue() == uniqueUserName.getText().toString()) {
                                            Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar
                                                    .make(coordinatorLayout, "Username already taken", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT);
                                            snackbar.show();
                                        } else {
                                            signingUpMethod();
                                        }
                                    } else {
                                        signingUpMethod();
                                    }
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                                }
                            });
```

But got this log:

```
W/SyncTree: Listen at /unique-usernames failed: DatabaseError: Permission denied
```

After doing some research, I find this answer: [Firebase Permission denied Error](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37477852/6144372)

Current security rules:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null"
  }
}
```

Though it solves the problem, this solution might be handy in testing phase, but what when publishing the app? Please let me know.

Comment: Can you add your current security rules to your question?

Comment: @AndréKool hey, please checkout the edited question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this situation you can simply extend your current rules to give everyone read access to your usernames like this:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null",
    "unique-usernames": {
        ".read": true
    }
  }
}
```

Also check out [the security docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/) for more info because you can do a lot more with your security rules.

Comment: hmm... well, would this be safe for security purposes?

Comment: Yes, people can only read what is under "unique-usernames" if they are not yet authenticated, they won't be able to read anything else in your dtabse. Also because there isn't a write rule they won't be able to change anything when they are not authenticated. And i also suggest you take some time to read the docs to see what possibilities you have withing the security rules.

Comment: @HammadNasir Also you can test your rules in the simulator, there is a button in the top right corner of your rules screen in the firebase console.

Comment: hey, bro.. please help with this too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39859960/i-want-to-store-the-opened-rooms-chat-by-clicking-on-different-buttons-at-diffe

Answer (score 0):

In Firebase best way is to Authorize the using [Firebase Authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/) and the for getting the list of users you have to maintain your database when user is registered successully using its [Firebase Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/). You can't maintain Authorized user list using only [Firebase Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/)

Comment: please help with this too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39859960/i-want-to-store-the-opened-rooms-chat-by-clicking-on-different-buttons-at-diffe