# How can I store the opened room's chat at unique locations in Firebase and then retrieve them?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I want to do something like this: suppose there are 5 chat rooms and the user can enter and chat in any chat room by pressing the respective button. So, he should be shown the chats of that room only and not overall chat. At what reference in the Firebase Database do these chats should be stored so that every time when user enters a room, he is shown only that room's chat?

One way I thought is by generating timestamp and storing the chat under it in Firebase Database and then fetching the chats from there, but when I'm trying to this a new timestamp is getting generated every time and the previous one under which chats are stored in the database is getting lost.

Here's how I'm generating the timestamp:

```
Long tsLong = System.currentTimeMillis()/1000;
String ts = tsLong.toString();
```

Here's how I'm storing chat under it:

```
mFirebaseDatabaseReference.child("chatmodel").child(ts).setValue(model);
```

How do I achieve this? Please help me.

Answer (score 2):

*To achieve this I would suggest you to re-structure your database. Avoid too much nesting and post the chat rooms/chat requests like this:*

So here you see two chat rooms under unique ids generated by **.push()** at the time of posting request. With one unique identifier for request with key **uniqueCharacter**.

```
{
      "-HFSSFG5647DDHD" : {
        "name" : "Some Name",
        "someOtherinfo" : "test",
        "timestamp" : 12443567,
        "uniqueCharacter" : "Request2"
      },
      "-YYTH6637FRFSHt5" : {
        "name" : "Some other name",
        "someOtherinfo" : "test",
        "timestamp" : 12443567,
        "uniqueCharacter" : "Request3"
      }
    }
```

Now the other user sees both these requests and once he clicks on some ***you get the unique id generated at the time of pushing and create a separate chat room for that particular push id using filters like this:***

If user selected ***request3*** then your database ref will be:

```
databaseRef.orderByChild("uniqueCharacter").equalTo("Request3");
```

***This will give you access to that particular push id which you can share among all those who chose this and create a common chat room with same id for all of them.***

Hope you get the basic idea here on achieving what you want.

*This is not a production example but just a basic one to give you an idea about better way of achieving your goal.*