# Realtime Database security [Android]

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-signin

All the docs I've found describe how to read and write data to Firebase Realtime Database when setting the privacy of the database to public, like here:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write

[Firebase Permission denied Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37477644/firebase-permission-denied-error)

How do I pass the Firebase user when I already have the authentication up and running to be validated when I need to read the data when my rules are like this:

```
 {
   "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null"
    }
 }
```

When I try like this:

```
   reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            String value = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
            Log.d("VERBOSE: ", "Value is: " + value);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Log.e("ERROR: ", "Failed to read database.", databaseError.toException());
        }
    });
```

I always get the exception

```
com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Firebase Database error: Permission denied
```

Best regards

Comment: How is `reference` defined?

Comment: private DatabaseReference reference = database.getReference("categories");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to pass anything as long as the user is successfully authenticated. Ensure you have authenticated the user using Firebase's Authentication API before calling Realtime Database.